# String replace on Ajax response before appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble updating a the response from a jQuery ajax request. What I need to be able to replace `myPage.aspx` with `/myfolder/myPage.aspx` before appending to the DOM. Is this possible with jQuery, or just plain Javascript?

Here's what part of the "data" looks like.

```
<a id="act_ExportXML" href="javascript:SubmitForm('myPage.aspx?test=Test','_blank','false','',null)">
```

I've tried things like setting `dataType` to `text` and `html`. Using a contains with something like `[a:href~="myPage.aspx"]`. I've tried using the `replaceAll("myPage.aspx", "/myfolder/myPage.aspx`, but no luck so far. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe this isn't possible at all?

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies, but I've got it working with this line of code, easier than I thought, but still wondering why replaceAll() wasn't working after converting the response to an jQuery object.

```
// Inside of ajax success callback

var html = data.replace(/myPage.aspx/g,"/myfolder/rdPage.aspx");
// append code here
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is not built-in JS. Can't you run the selector on the `a` elements **after** appending them to the DOM? You may as well create a jQuery object to run that selector on, but there will be no difference in the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your response is contained in a variable called `responseText`, you could try the following:

```
$(responseText).find('a').attr('href', function() {
    return this.href.replace('myPage.aspx', '/myfolder/myPage.aspx');
});
```

That should create actual elements out of your HTML, find all the `<a>` elements, then set their `href` attributes to the updated value (replacing `myPage.aspx` with `/myfolder/myPage.aspx`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this within the success callback and didn't seem to make any difference. I don't have a responseText variable, but I do have "data", for example: success: function(data){
                $(data).find('a').attr('href', function() {
                this.href.replace('myPage.aspx', '/myfolder/myPage.aspx');
            });

Comment: Anthony, didn't you forget a `return` there?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, I did. That's what I get for writing answers quickly just before I'm about to leave, edited to include that.